# Can´t get the SecKey UnsafeMutablePointer in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, encryption, swift, rsa, unmanaged

I am working in a project in swift, involving RSA Encryption, and I am stuck with a pointer  problem as follows:

I have a global `var publicKey: SecKey?` optional value, and I need to get the `UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<SecKey>?>` pointer to it, that is the data type required in the  `SecKeyGeneratePair` function.

I am trying to define the pointer as:

```
var keyPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<SecKey>?>(publicKey!)
```

But the compiler complains with a **Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type @lvalue SecKey** error

According to the **Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C** book, In the **Core Foundation** and **Unmanaged Objects** section, it states that the `Unmanaged<T>` structure provides 2 methods `takeUnretainedValue()` and `takeRetainedValue()`. but trying to implement them, gives the following error

```
var keyPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<SecKey>?>(publicKey!.takeRetainedValue())
```

**'SecKey' does not have a member named 'takeRetainedValue'**

Any help to work this out will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var publicKey: SecKey?
var privateKey: SecKey?

var publicKeyUnManaged:Unmanaged<SecKey>?
var privateKeyUnManaged:Unmanaged<SecKey>?
let dic:[String:String] = [kSecAttrKeyType:kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits:"2048"]
SecKeyGeneratePair(dic, &publicKeyUnManaged, &privateKeyUnManaged)

publicKey = publicKeyUnManaged?.takeRetainedValue()
privateKey = privateKeyUnManaged?.takeRetainedValue()
```

You don't have to create `UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<SecKey>?>` manually. As mentioned in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_16),

> When a function is declared as taking an UnsafeMutablePointer argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - nil, which is passed as a null pointer
> - An UnsafeMutablePointer value
> - An in-out expression whose operand is a stored lvalue of type Type, which is passed as the address of the lvalue
> - An in-out [Type] value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array, and lifetime-extended for the duration of the call

In this case, we can use 3rd "in-out" expression.

Answer (score 1):

for Swift 2.1 it isn't working with Unmanaged, the right version is:

```
var publicKey: SecKey?
var privateKey: SecKey?

let dic:[String:String] = [kSecAttrKeyType:kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits:"2048"]
SecKeyGeneratePair(dic, &publicKey, &privateKey)
```